# Strategy which opens trade if (1) SMA20 upwards (2) ADX 30+ (3)falling under SMA20

Tags: breakout, adx

This script should open a trade under the following conditions

1. SMA20 goes up
2. Last closing falls under SMA20
3. ADX is above 30

it shall use the highest high of the last 5 candels as take profit and the lowest low of the last 5 candles as stop loss.

But it leeps opening trades when SMA goes down...

```
bool openTrade = false

fiveCandleHigh = ta.highest (5) [1]
fiveCandleLow = ta.lowest(5)[1]

[_, _, adx] = ta.dmi(1, 1)

if close < ta.sma(close, 20) and ta.ema(close,20) > ta.ema(close,20)[5] and adx > 30
    openTrade := true

if (openTrade == true)
    strategy.entry("LE", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("LE", from_entry = "LE", limit=fiveCandleHigh, stop=fiveCandleLow)
```